# Flutter rounded square box with different color for each Corner

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

### How to make this type of square box with different colour for each Corner side.

Example showing in the image.

Please help me to make a design in flutter.

[image]

Comment: make a custom `Decoration` class

Comment: can you provide code @pskink. i try this but does not make this type of design.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L19

Comment: Thanks brother it's help me @pskink .